# Passing ViewData from C# Controller to View to Angular controller

Tags: c#, angular, model-view-controller, .net-core

So I'm a pretty new AngularJS user and this is my first working with .NET Core and attempting to modify code I've inherited.  I'm reading in a file using StreamReader and have the number of rows being passed in to my Home Index view successfully.

```
    public IActionResult Index(int? period, int? length)
            {
                if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    ViewData["Name"] = GetUsersName();
                    return View();
                } else
                {
                    return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
                }
                ViewData["period"] = period;
                ViewData["length"] = length;
            }
```

From there I'm looking to move the int length to my View so I might pass the value to my Angular controller for a simple calculation.

Home Index header:

```
        @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        var user = Json.Serialize(ViewData["Name"]);
        var length = Json.Serialize(ViewData["length"]);
    }

    <div class="" ng-controller="homeController as home"
         ng-init="home.initValues(); home.move(@length)">
```

```
            <div id="myProgress">
                <div id="myBar">0%</div>
            </div>
            <button style="margin: 5px" ng-click='home.move()'>Refresh Status</button>
            <div>Stream Length: @length</div>

            </div>
```

I'm attempting to print the variable to screen to simply see the int value is passing correctly, although it's only ever shown "null".

The ultimate goal is to populate the value within my Angular controller to replace the hard-coded value "23894" with the most current row count of the file I've uploaded.

```
    self.move = function (streamLength){ 

            var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
            var percent = self.variances[0].totalVariances;
            console.log("Total variances: " + percent);
            console.log("Stream length: " + streamLength);

            var width = 1;
            var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
            function frame() {
                if (width >= (percent / 23894) * 100) {
                    clearInterval(id);
                } else {
                    width++;
                    elem.style.width = width + '%';
                    elem.innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
                }
            }
            console.log("Percentage: " + width);
            console.log(percent / 23894);
        }
```

Final calculation will help select the appropriate "fill" for my status bar.

[Status Bar Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMTAx.png)

Any recommendations or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Don't post your code in images. Edit the post to include the code in a text format.

Comment: Please use Stackoverflow text editor to input your code. It makes it much easier for others to view your code and make suggestions/debug. Nobody can copy/paste from images.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, have updated code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Well I successfully managed to get the variable passed to the controller.  From what I can tell it was two things.  First the C# Home Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(int? period, int? length)
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                ViewData["Name"] = GetUsersName();
                ViewData["length"] = length;
                return View();
            } else
            {
                return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
            }
            ViewData["period"] = period;
        }
```

Moving the ViewData population BEFORE the return View in the If loop was critical.  Code was never reaching before and was kicking out before the ViewData was ever reached.

Second seems to be that I wasn't properly passing in the variable to the controller.  This worked:

```
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
        var user = Json.Serialize(ViewData["Name"]);
        var length = Json.Serialize(ViewData["length"]);
        var streamLength = (ViewData["length"]);
     }

        <div class="" ng-controller="homeController as home"
             ng-init="home.initValues(); home.move(@length)">
                <div id="myProgress">
                    <div id="myBar">0%</div>
                </div>
                <button style="margin: 5px" ng-click='home.move(@length)'>Refresh Status</button>
                <div>Stream Length: @streamLength </div>

                </div>
```

Lessons learned.